# Store reference of struct in other struct

Tags: rust

I have two structs. `App` and `Item`.

What I want to achieve is to store an `Item` in the `items` vector of the `App` struct by passing a mutable reference to the `Item`s constructor.

```rust
pub struct App<'a> {
    items: Vec<&'a Item>
}

impl<'a> App<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> App<'a> {
        App { items: Vec::new() }
    }
    pub fn register_item(&mut self, item: &'a Item) {
        self.items.push(item);
    }
}

pub struct Item;

impl Item {
    pub fn new(app: &mut App) -> Item {
        let item = Item;
        app.register_item(&item);
        item
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new();

    let item = Item::new(&mut app);;
}
```

The code thows the following error:

```
test.rs:8:28: 8:32 error: `item` does not live long enough
test.rs:8         app.register_item(&item);
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This already has an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135409/rust-borrowed-pointers-and-lifetimes and in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608823/how-to-model-complex-recursive-data-structures-graphs

Comment: Apart from the immediate error, storing pointers in the Vec seems wrong. You almost certainly want a `Vec<Item>` in `App`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While `Rc` might be correct for your use case, it's good to understand why you are getting the error you are. Please read [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) as it has a much more in-depth discussion about why your code cannot work as-is. A simplified explanation follows.

Let's look at your constructor:

```
fn new(app: &mut App) -> Item {
    let item = Item;
    app.register_item(&item);
    item
}
```

Here, we create a new `Item` on the stack at some address. Let's pretend that address is 0x1000. We then take the address of `item` (0x1000) and store it into the `Vec` inside the `App`. We then return `item` to the calling function, which resides in a *different stack frame*. That means that the address of `item` will change, which means that 0x1000 is no longer guaranteed to point to a valid `Item`! This is how Rust prevents you from making whole classes of memory errors!

I'd say that you'd normally see this written as:

```
fn main() {
    let item = Item;
    let mut app = App::new();
    app.register_item(&item);
}
```

This will have the same problem if you tried to return `app` or `item` from this function, as the address will change.

---

If you have a straight-forward tree structure, I'd advocate for simply letting the parent nodes own the children:

```
struct App {
    items: Vec<Item>
}

impl App {
    fn new() -> App {
        App { items: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn register_item(&mut self, item: Item) {
        self.items.push(item);
    }
}

pub struct Item;

fn main() {
    let mut app = App::new();
    app.register_item(Item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is to use `Rc`.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Item;

impl Item {

    pub fn new(app: &mut App) -> Rc<Item> {
        let item = Rc::new(Item);
        app.register_item(item.clone());
        item
    }

}

pub struct App {
    items: Vec<Rc<Item>>
}

...
```