# Cyclic reference does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I have a cyclic graph-like structure where nodes refer to other nodes. I've removed some stuff for brevity. I'm still just beginning to learn Rust, and I used [Rust borrowed pointers and lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135409/rust-borrowed-pointers-and-lifetimes) and https://github.com/nrc/r4cppp/blob/master/graphs/src/rc_graph.rs as references

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::*;

fn main() {
    let node1 = Node::new(1);
    let node0 = Node::new(0);

    node0.borrow_mut().parent = Some(node1.clone());
    node1.borrow_mut().parent = Some(node0.clone());

    //works
    println!("Value of node0: {}", node0.borrow().value);

    //neither of the following work
    println!("Value of node0.parent: {}", node0.borrow().parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().value);
    println!("Value of node0: {}", node0.borrow().get_parent().borrow().value);
}

struct Node {
    value: i32,
    parent:  Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>
}

impl Node{

    fn new(val: i32) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            value: val,
            parent: None
        }))
    }


    fn get_parent(&self) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
        self.parent.as_ref().unwrap().clone()
    }
}
```

I'm trying to output the value of node's parent, but I get the following compile errors:

```
16 |     println!("Value of node0.parent: {}", node0.borrow().parent.as_ref().unwrap().borrow().value);
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
```

and

```
17 |     println!("Value of node0: {}", node0.borrow().get_parent().borrow().value);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ does not live long enough
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split the borrows out from the `println!` calls:

```
// Borrow them separately, so their scopes are larger.
let n0_borrowed = node0.borrow();
let n1_borrowed = node1.borrow();
let n0_parent = n0_borrowed.parent.as_ref().unwrap();
let n1_parent = n1_borrowed.parent.as_ref().unwrap();

println!("Value of node0: {}", node0.borrow().value);
println!("Value of node0.parent: {}", n0_parent.borrow().value);

println!("Value of node1: {}",node1.borrow().value);
println!("Value of node1.parent: {}", n1_parent.borrow().value);
```

[Here it is running in the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c1a60d4390145584efd24c2ba1408f1d&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Essentially, the borrowed references aren't living long enough when you chain all the calls together. Splitting them out increases their scope and they live longer.

Comment: I know you have already accepted this - but I updated the Playground example to split each borrow out. Hopefully that helps a bit more.

Comment: Ha, that was much simpler than I was expecting. Thank you!